# ColdFusion schedule task using cfinclude?

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-9

I have 15 separate .cfm pages that are scheduled in separate nightly processes. All of that I would like to put in one page and include all other pages to run one after the other. I tried to do this, in ScheduleTask.cfm I have included:

```
<cfinclude template="page1.cfm">
<cfinclude template="page2.cfm">
<cfinclude template="page3.cfm">
```

I tried to put in my broweser url ScheduleTask.cfm but I got and error:

```
Detail  The routine standardSelect has been declared twice in different templates.
Message     Routines cannot be declared more than once.
```

Each of my includes generates excel page from `cfquery`. Also should I have try catch block around the includes and what else I should be checking?

Also I tired to approach this problem using struct and the loop:

```
<cftry>
    <cfset rptCFMFiles = {
            file1 = "page1.cfm",
            file2 = "page2.cfm",
            file3 = "page3.cfm",
        }>

    <cfloop collection="#rptCFMFiles#" item="key">
        <cfoutput>
            <cfinclude template="#rptCFMFiles[key]#">
        </cfoutput>
    </cfloop>

    <cfcatch>
        <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Same error showed again:

```
Detail: The routine standardSelect has been declared twice in different templates.
Message: Routines cannot be declared more than once.
```

If anyone can help please let me know.

Comment: I wrote a separate scheduling tool (w/CF front-end) to generate CRON tasks that run BAT files w/CURL requests (saving result w/API callbacks) so that scripts can be executed serially and so that a single CF error doesn't abort the entire process. This approach is portable, doesn't time-out & doesn't require any CFThreads. (I started doing this due to limitations in the CFSchedule admin.)

Comment: @JamesMoberg Can you show any example of that tool that you use? Thanks.

Comment: I use nnCron LITE for Windows. I use CF to generate a plain text CRONTAB file. Each task executes a BAT file w/1 or more web requests (or non-web request) Here's sample CRONTAB & BAT files: https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/96cd5afd12fc19513ef3c2a882a38f9b

Answer (score 2):

Your specific error is that at least two of your included files either have, or include a .cfm page with a function named `standardSelect`.  You have to find all those functions and do something about it.  What you do depends on the details of what you find.

Your general idea is something that we actually do.  We have some more details you might not have thought of.  We have a custom tag to expand on the `<cfinclude`.  Not only does it do try/catch, which you did think of, but it logs results.  If the job executed successfully, it logs that.  If an error occurs, it logs the details.

But wait, there's more.  We have other scheduled jobs that read those logs.  If something went wrong, a report of what happened is sent to people who can do something about it.  In fact, I got one of those reports this morning.

Comment: Do you have any example of how and what is the best way to organize this? I have output in each of my reports that will show on the screen with the information like Report name - time and date. Also is it better to keep each report in separate .cfm or put all of them in one .cfm file. I'm not sure if that can cause any problem and if there is any difference how fast task will be executed.

Comment: The concept of a scheduled job outputting to a screen is unusual, to be polite.

Comment: I do not see what is unusual if I output time&date when report is generated. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: i guess it would be unusual because no one will see the output - unless you log it somehow or email the output.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use cfhttp in one cfm multiple times to call each URL. In serial. You schedule that one cfm, which runs all the cfhttp's.

Comment: That is an interesting solution. It does get round having to worry cross dependancies